# Error doing rbind at rmarkdown in RStudio

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, rbind

I'm new using RMarkdown and I'm having several problems with the data frames I want to plot.

I have a data frame with 3 rows and 5 columns called a1, and then I have a vector with five elements. As I need a new data frame with both of them, I do an rbind.

```r
a<-as.data.frame(c("a","b","c"))
b1<-c(1:3)
b2<-c(1:3)
b3<-c(1:3)
b4<-c(1:3)
a1<-cbind(a,b1,b2,b3,b4)
c<-c("Promedio",7.55,6.74,9.34,12.88)
a1<-rbind(a1,c)
```

It seems to work well outside the rmarkdown but when I knit it I have this error:

> Error in rbindlis(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : Item 2 has 1 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 13 columns. If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument 'fil' to TRUE. Calls:  ... eval -> eval -> rbind -> rbind ->  -> rbindlist

Comment: what is `a` in the cbind above? When we knit the knitter does not use the environment variables you have created in your rstudio session. Please clear your environment and try again. This is usually the cause of most issues.

Comment: We could better help you if you would post a minimal reproducible example. Take your Rmarkdown document and remove any lines that aren't necessary for reproducing your error, then post that code here and we can help you figure it out.

Comment: When I put your (fixed) code with the definition of `a` into an `Rmd` file I get the warning `invalid factor level, NA generated`. When I add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` the code runs without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal working example of what you're trying to do. It's a working example, because it reproduces your problem of using `rbind` within a knitr document. It's minimal, because most everything that isn't relevant to reproducing your issue has been stripped away. Try knitting this and if it works, then modify it to suit your needs. If you have problems, strip away everything that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem and then post the complete runnable code so we can look at it.

````
---
output: html_document
---

Some text

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(text = c("a", "b"),
                b1 = 1:2,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

c <- c("Promedio",7.55)
rbind(df,c)

```
````

Answer (score 1):

Is not working becuase object **c** is a vector instead of a **data.frame**

```
a<-as.data.frame(c("a","b","c"))
names(a) #Returns the ugly "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")"
names(a) <- "a" 
names(a) #Returns a

b1<-c(1:3)
b2<-c(1:3)
b3<-c(1:3)
b4<-c(1:3)

a1<-cbind(a,b1,b2,b3,b4)


#c<-c("Promedio",7.55,6.74,9.34,12.88) This is a vector
#But it should be a data.frame

c <- data.frame(a = c("Promedio"),
            b1 = c(7.55),
            b2 = c(6.74),
            b3 = c(9.34),
            b4 = c(12.88))

a1 <-rbind(a1,c) 
a1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers but I finnaly decided to do all the data frame again as it was not working at all.  I´m not able to share the original data base as it is confidential but this is the final script:

```
#I started doing a data frame from a dcast with four quarters (trimestre I...) and
# a flag (0-1)

a<-dcast(b,RSdRTelecom~Trimestre+Fg_Deuda,fun=sum,value.var="u") 

#then I created diferent vectors for each column for the new data frame
Trimestre_I<-c(a$`1_1`/(a$`1_0`+a$`1_1`))
Trimestre_II<-c(a$`2_1`/(a$`2_0`+a$`2_1`))
Trimestre_III<-c(a$`3_1`/(a$`3_0`+a$`3_1`))
Trimestre_IV<-c(a$`4_1`/(a$`4_0`+a$`4_1`))
#Then I created a vector for the mean values 
Promedio<-c(sum(a$`1_1`)/(sum(a$`1_0`)+sum(a$`1_1`)),
     sum(a$`2_1`)/(sum(a$`2_0`)+sum(a$`2_1`)),
     sum(a$`3_1`)/(sum(a$`3_0`)+sum(a$`3_1`)),
     sum(a$`4_1`)/(sum(a$`4_0`)+sum(a$`4_1`)))

#I create a new data frame with cbind by Trimestre...
a<-cbind(Trimestre_I,Trimestre_II,Trimestre_III, Trimestre_IV)
#Then do a rbind with the mean vector 
a<-rbind(a,Promedio)
#Finnaly, I added a new vector with the names of the groups
Grupo<-c("SdR Telecom 1,2,3", "SdR Telecom 4,5", "Vacío", "Promedio")
a<-cbind(Grupo,a)
```